# Different footer for each section in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to have a different footer in each section of a generated document.
However, it seems that modifying the footer in one sections modifies it in all sections.
Using the 'first_page_footer' property does not seem to help.
The minimal example below illustrates my issue:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.section import WD_SECTION

document = Document()
n_pages  = 5
for pp in range(0, n_pages):
    if pp < n_pages - 1:
        document.add_section(WD_SECTION.NEW_PAGE)
    current_section                                      = document.sections[-1]
    current_section.footer.paragraphs[0].text            = str(pp)
    current_section.first_page_footer.paragraphs[0].text = str(pp)
    
document.save('Apple.doc')
# All footers contain the number 4

document.sections[1].footer.paragraphs[0].text = 'Banana'
document.save('Banana.doc')
# All footers contain the word Banana
```

Answer (score 1):

The linked_to_previous property need to be set to False (otherwise, changing footer in one section changes to all previous ones). Below the corrected example.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.section import WD_SECTION

document = Document()
n_pages  = 5
for pp in range(0, n_pages):
    current_section                                         = document.sections[-1]
    current_section.footer.is_linked_to_previous            = False
    current_section.footer.paragraphs[0].text               = str(pp)
    if pp < n_pages - 1:
        document.add_section(WD_SECTION.NEW_PAGE)
    
document.save('Apple.doc')
#Footers contain number 0, 1, 2,3 ,4

document.sections[1].footer.paragraphs[0].text = 'Banana'
document.save('Banana.doc')
# Only the second page has the word Banana
```